# Different geometry Viewport vs Render in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck on this stupid thing.
This object looks completely deformed on the render vs how I see it in the viewport.
The project is a bit messy, I used .xps files from ripped games models, so I don't even understand what could be wrong.
I checked layer visibilities and it should be fine, I tried removing the armature modifier but it's still the same. They're both at 32 samples. I'll attach the blender file and the screenshots. THX!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10duDmQuQjRbMByTHLNjWnmO6YzCnLByb/view?usp=sharing

[image: Viewport]

[image: Render]

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are duplicated. Try click selecting then moving them. I looked at the star and there are three duplicates there in particular. This fixed the shading issue.